# What size can make the video fit to screen in After effect

Tags: adobe-after-effects, size

Creating a video. With aspect ratio of 9/16. Why the video is not fitting in the mobile screen. Any suggestion whats going wrong. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it's not related to video dimensions. Maybe be phone or the application you're using isn't able to stretch it fully to the display. In Android phones, even if the video width less than 1080 pixels, it still gets stretched to widths.

Comment: Wait, did you try changing Resolution greater than Quarter?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Video editing is off-topic here. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is with Resolution you've selected. In the dropdown, select **Full** instead of **Quarter** and then export. It should work fine (unless your phone or the app you're using to open this video doesn't *stretch* the video to full screen, for some reasons).

[image]

You can change same from Composition window (*Resolution/Down Sample Factor Popup*) also.